# Are claims from conspiracy websites off-topic?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, off-topic

I had a [comment](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/19730/are-there-1-million-foreign-troops-in-the-us#comment76764_19730) on one of my questions that started like this:

> in fact it's a conspiracy theory website. The mere fact that something is mentioned as "fact" there almost certainly means it's not.

Does that mean I can't use claims from conspiracy websites here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are certainly not off topic as long as they are notable - believed by a lot of people. There is nothing preventing those claims to be relevant enough to be interesting here.

The comment was a pseudo-answer and I deleted it - comments should not attempt to answer the questions, of course.